# Simple question about DG-algebras

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras, dg-categories

Considering the following conditions for two DG-algebras $A$ and $B$:

1) There exists quasi-isomorphic DG-algebra morphism $A \to B$.

2) There exists a DG-algebra $C$ and two quasi-isomorphic DG-algebra morphisms $C \to A$ and $C \to B$.

3) There exists a DG-category $\mathcal{C}$ and two objects $x,y \in \mathcal{C}$, such that $x$ is isomorphic to $y$ in the homotopy category of $\mathcal{C}$, and $A$ is isomorphic to $End(x)$ and $B$ is isomorphic to $End(y)$.

4) The DG-categories $A-mod$ and $B-mod$ are DG-equivalent (meaning, there exists a DG-category $\mathcal{C}$ and quasi-equivalences $\mathcal{C} \to A-mod$ and $\mathcal{C} \to B-mod$).

Am I correct in my understanding that $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 4$, but $4 \not\Rightarrow 3 \not\Rightarrow 2 \not\Rightarrow 1$?

Is it correct also that $2$ is equivalent to having an $A_{\infty}$-equivalence $A \to B$ (something like that)?

Comment: Something is wrong with condition 3. I think you might want to say something about $x,y$ being isomorphic in the underlying category of $\mathcal{C}$ cause as written, the disjoint union of two objects can make such a category.

Comment: @Pax Kivimae: Oh, of course. I actually wanted them to be isomorphic in the homotopy category.

Comment: So the implication 1 => 2 is immediate, and 2 =/=> 1 is also true (take a quasi-iso B -> A with no homotopy inverse, e.g. if A has is torsion and B has none). There is not an implication 1 => 4 unless you restrict $A$-mod and $B$-mod to something like semi-free/ semi-projective / cofibrant-fibrant DG-modules. It is not the case that 4 implies any of the others: all of 1, 2, and 3 imply that $A$ and $B$ have isomorphic homology, while 4 is satisfied if $A$ and $B$ are Morita equivalent algebras (like $\Bbb Z$ and $M_d(\Bbb Z)$) concentrated in degree zero.

Comment: If you restrict to semi-free / semi-projective / cofibrant DG-modules, then 1 and 2 imply 4 (under more assumptions (3) does too, but the worry is that $Hom(x,y)$ and $Hom(y,x)$ might be nasty bimodules). I am less sure about the relations between 3 and the other items. Unfortunately 2 is not equivalent to an $A_\infty$ equivalence unless $A$ and $B$ are free over $\Bbb Z$ or algebras over a field (we need to construct a chain homotopy equivalence).

Comment: @Tayler Lawson: Thank you for the reply. Maybe I use non-standard terminology? but think that 1 implies 4. By A-mod I mean the dg-category of A-modules dg-localized along quasi-isomorphisms. For example, theorem 10.12.5.1 from Bernstein-Lunts book says that A-mod is equivalent to B-mod if A\to B is a quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: @Tayler Lawson: I guess, since you say "restricting to cofibrant DG-modules", that you understood my A-mod as the DG-category of A-modules before localizing along quasi-isomorphisms perhaps?

Comment: @Sasha My apologies for misunderstanding, I did not understand that a dg-localization was involved.